# recognize a specific element order pattern in R vector

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a list of vectors that each vector look like this

> c("Japan", "USA", "country", "Japan", "source", "country", "UK",  "source", "country", "USA")

My task is to extract the country name after the first c("source", "country"), so "UK" will be the country name to be extracted in this example. In all vectors, c("source", "country") will be followed by a country name, so I just need to extract the element right after the first c("source", "country").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to find the first index of where `source` comes before `country` and add 2:

```
x <- c("Japan", "USA", "country", "Japan", "source", "country", "UK", "source", "country", "USA")

x[which((x == "source")[-length(x)] & (x == "country")[-1])[1] + 2]
# [1] "UK"
```

Comment: Similarly : `x[which.max(head(x, -1) == 'source' & tail(x, -1) == 'country') + 2]`

Comment: @RonakShah - I avoided `which.max()` as it will still return a result in the case of no matches - safer to use `which()` although OP does say in all vectors there will be a match.

Answer (score 3):

We could try using a paste collapse regex approach here:

```r
v <- c("Japan", "USA", "country", "Japan", "source", "country", "UK", "source", "country", "USA")
terms <- paste(v, collapse="|")
country <- sub("^.*?\\|source\\|country\\|(.*?)\\|.*$", "\\1", terms)
country

[1] "UK"
```

The approach used here is to form a pipe-delimited list of terms, looking like:

```
Japan|USA|country|Japan|source|country|UK|source|country|USA
```

Then, we search for the first `|source|country|` occurrence and retain the term coming immediately after that.